# Single Column recursive query Output

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, recursive-query

Can anybody please help me out on below query output based on below tabular data.

Pattern : AVRA1 is linked with 979798. now in 979798 we have (AVRA1,SHUBH2,MOM). Now SHUBH2 is linked 979798,979799. Now I need to check for 979799 and find out which col2 are linked and so on.

**TABLE A**

```
  col1  col2
979798  avra1
979798  shubh2
979798  mom
979798  shubh2
979799  shubh2
979799  papa
979799  papa
979800  papa
979800  neha
1   abc
2   xyz
3   asd
4   fgv
5   jug
6   iuy
7   oij
```

**INPUT**

AVRA1

**OUTPUT**

```
    col1    col2
    979798  avra1
    979798  shubh2
    979798  mom
    979799  shubh2
    979799  papa
    979800  papa
    979800  neha
```

Comment: Please explain, what is your expected data?

Comment: Hi Jim, I have edited the post. could you please let me know if this makes sense now.

Comment: Hi APC, thanks for pointing this. I will make sure to post the question in more framed manner.

Comment: `select distinct col1, col2 from table_a` will give the posted output. Not sure what you expect to do with table B. Nor why you've tagged this `[recursive-query]`

Comment: Hi APC. I have have added few more data in table A. now if you can see i will input 'AVRA1' as a input. Can you please help me out on the output.

Comment: Hi APC. I have tagged this recursive query because of below pattern. AVRA1 is linked with 979798. now in 979798 we have (AVRA1,SHUBH2,MOM). Now SHUBH2 is linked 979798,979799. Now I need to check for 979799 and find out which col2 are linked and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If i look at your data, you are just selecting distinct records. Is that what are you expecting. If so use below query.

```
select distinct col1, col2 from table_name;
```

[image]

But not sure what is the use of **TABLE B**. What is the purpose of mentioning in the question?

Comment: Hi Jim, I have added few more data in table A

Comment: What is the pattern to get that out put? Can you explain in detail

Comment: Sure.. AVRA1 is linked with 979798. now in 979798 we have (AVRA1,SHUBH2,MOM). Now SHUBH2 is linked 979798,979799. Now I need to check for 979799 and find out which col2 are linked and so on.